# Difficulty Integrating Powerapps, Flow, and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powerapps

I built a form in Powerapps that I want to workflow and placed it in SharePoint 2013.  When trying to add email addresses of employees, I get an error and it wont pull in outlook email address.  i type in the email addresses manually, and it wont accept them.

Also, I'm unable to save my progress because of the erros.  The errors have to be resolved in order to save.

The errors are simply fields (email address field) that is highlighted in red.  But it doesn't explain why it is an error / why field is highlighted in red.  only that you have to fix it somehow

Comment: Can you add more details about the error that you get? And the formula / expression that you are using to get the error?

Comment: Please provide a a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve